# Who is Brett White?

Tags: discussion

If you also frequent Gaming.SE, then you are probably already familiar with me. If not, you can check out [this post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/who-is-brett-white-and-why-is-he-a-moderator) and also forge ahead with your reading eyes.

My name is Brett and I'm a member of CHAOS, Stack Exchange's new community evangelism and outreach team. Our main goal is to make the sites more fun and awesome for you and this growing community. I'm going to also help with some site maintenance, mostly just editing the titles of questions on the home page every morning and afternoon to make sure they are complete sentences full of grammatical goodness.

If anyone has any suggestions for how to make this community more awesome, with contests, promotional events, merchandise, etc, please let me know. I'll be around!

I'm very excited to be a part of this community. And I will continue to provide ridiculously detailed answers to any and all Marvel Comics questions that come our way.

Comment: I'm *really* tempted to submit an answer 'Brett White is Spartacus', but I think that would give up my secret identity as also being Spartacus.

Comment: @Brett - how are we to let you know of our suggestions? Should we post them here, or email you or something else?

Comment: I think that leaving suggestions here is fine. It'll corral all of them in one special place.

Comment: Assistance with promotion would be awesome, and answering questions is fantastic from anyone, of course.  WRT to editing, can you please be extremely light-touched here, at least at first?  IMO the community is doing an excellent job of this, and we're more familiar (presumably) with the accepted norms of the site.  (The last time we had SE staff actively doing things was a disaster; since we've had our lovely community mods things are way better).  In most cases, I expect we'll fix obvious errors ourselves, and in questionable cases, it would be better to ask here on meta first.

Comment: BTW please also avoid, as much as possible, editing large numbers of questions at once, unless you have special "doesn't make this active" powers.  This screws up the "recent questions" RSS feed and active questions main page (e.g. the recent work at parenting.se).  What I personally like to do is *periodically* find the *occasional* old question that could use an edit, *and* use some more promotion.

Answer (score 4):

I really don't like prefixing titles of identification questions with “Can you identify this book about”. It's redundant with the tags, and doesn't flow naturally, in addition to being extremely verbose.

Comment: Agreed, even though I was doing it. If we can come up with a standardized way of doing it, I'd be all for it. I guess "Story Identification: An X does Y in space with Z". The problem I've been running across is that usually story identification questions lack actual details of the story in the title, which they should have for SEO purposes.

Comment: @BrettWhiteΨ I absolutely approve of getting more details of the story; what I disapprove of is including “Can you identify”, or worse “Story identification:” (which is long and not a complete sentence anyway). “An X does Y in space with Z” is a perfectly cromulent title.

Comment: Great! Duly noted, and will now start working with that method. That actually helps, because the time I've wasted wracking my brain with those story identification questions is time I can't get back. Streamlining the process!

Answer (score 1):

> If anyone has any suggestions for how to make this community more awesome, with contests, promotional events, merchandise, etc, please let me know.

Maybe we could Put [a scifi.stackexchang add on the moon](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DefaceOfTheMoon)!

Gnol evil Bulgroz!!!

Comment: We all saw how well that worked when Chairface tried it on the Tick. Right? We ALL saw that.

Comment: @Brett White, this comment makes you my new favorite person ever. Kudos.

Comment: @Brett White I was not referring to the Chairface incident, I was referring to the Zorglub incident. But, you guys know Zorglub, right? ... (cricket) ... oh, ok then, never mind...